# Cannot install Android Test Orchestrator using adb

Tags: android, curl, adb

I'm trying to install orchestrator-1.4.0.apk from [here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.0) but I get this error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK: Failed to parse /data/app/vmdl881333462.tmp/base.apk: Failed to load asset path /data/app/vmdl881333462.tmp/base.apk].
```

Beforehand this file gets uploaded with `curl -O <url>`

Why do I get this error?

**UPD**

I am using these commands

1. ADB

```
adb install -g -r --force-queryable orchestrator-1.4.0.apk
```

2. curl

```
curl -O https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/androidx/test/orchestrator/1.4.0/orchestrator-1.4.0.apk
```

Comment: thanks. Same issue by using `adb install orchestrator-1.4.0.apk`?

Comment: @Lino Yes, same

Answer (score 0):

The location of these artifacts has changed.

You can get them here:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/orchestrator/1.4.0/orchestrator-1.4.0.apk
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/services/test-services/1.4.0/test-services-1.4.0.apk

This bash script will download the artifacts to $HOME and install them. You can easily modify the version.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

VERSION="1.5.0-alpha01"

ORCHESTRATOR_APK_PATH="$HOME/Desktop/orchestrator.apk"
TEST_SERVICES_APK_PATH="$HOME/Desktop/test-services.apk"

if [ ! -f "$ORCHESTRATOR_APK_PATH" ]; then
    curl -o "$ORCHESTRATOR_APK_PATH" "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/orchestrator/$VERSION/orchestrator-$VERSION.apk" 2>/dev/null    
fi

if [ ! -f "$TEST_SERVICES_APK_PATH" ]; then
    curl -o "$TEST_SERVICES_APK_PATH" "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/services/test-services/$VERSION/test-services-$VERSION.apk" 2>/dev/null
fi

DEVICE_API_LEVEL="$(adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk)"

FORCE_QUERYABLE_OPTION=""
if [[ "$DEVICE_API_LEVEL" -ge 30 ]]; then
    FORCE_QUERYABLE_OPTION="--force-queryable"
fi

# uninstall old versions
adb uninstall androidx.test.services || true
adb uninstall androidx.test.orchestrator || true

# Install the test orchestrator.
adb install "$FORCE_QUERYABLE_OPTION" -r "$ORCHESTRATOR_APK_PATH"

# Install test services.
adb install "$FORCE_QUERYABLE_OPTION" -r "$TEST_SERVICES_APK_PATH"
```